# Probability theory: P(B given A) versus P(NON B given A)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, logic

If in a probability distribution P(B given A) is high does it follow from that that P(NON B given A) is high?

Comment: That seems immediately counterintuitive ... do you mean to say that if the one is high, the other one is *low*?

Comment: Yes. Think of this set theoretically: the more A is included in B the more B given A is high and the more NON B given A is low.

Comment: OK, you'll want to edit your question then ...

Comment: P.S. I notice that you ask a good number of questions but rarely upvote or accept ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *always* true that $P(B|A) + P(B'|A)=1$.

($P(B'|A)$ stands for $P(NON \ B | A)$. Sometimes we use $P(B^C|A)$ or $P(\neg B|A)$)

Informal explanation: If we are given $A$, then what about $B$?  Well, it is of course always true that $B$ is true or not. That is, either $B$ or $NON \ B$ (again, more typically represented as $B'$, or $B^C$ or $\neg B$) has to be true, no matter whatever else is true or not true.

So if the one is 'high', then the other is 'low'.

Comment: Does ' stand for "not"?

Comment: @Fishermansfriend Yes, that's right

Answer (score 1):

$P(.| A)$ is just a probability distribution. So $P(\lnot B|A) = 1-P(B|A)$.

So they're just two numbers that sum to $1$. If one is very small, the other is almost one, etc.
So *no* to your question as stated.